# How to set datatime today now for search?

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to refine my value today but i cant set. Can help me!

```
<input type="date" name="start" value="2022-12-25"/>
<input type="date" name="end" value="2022-12-25"/>
```

I want to refine my value today but i cant set. Can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to set the default date with js:

```
<input type="date" name="start" />
<input type="date" name="end" />


@section Scripts{

<script>
    $(function(){
            document.getElementsByName('start')[0].valueAsDate = new Date();
            document.getElementsByName('end')[0].valueAsDate = new Date();

    })
</script>
}
```

result:

[image]

Comment: when i search i want to keep current datetime value how do i do?

Comment: Can you explain more about how  you search?

Answer (score 0):

the information you provided is not sufficient. Provide which language/technology you are working, i figured it out that you are looking for help in Microsoft technology stack.

Coming to the point you want to print/show Current Datetime value, for that, According to me Create variable storage Current Datetime and bind it to the Html

for Ex.

```
var CurrentDateTime = DateTime.now;
```

this will set Current date time to the variable  and in HTML MVC if you are using razor view / pages
you just need to bind that value to it.
there are multiple ways for that.
but here i would like to GO with ViewBag approach
you can do like following

```
ViewBag.CurrentDatetime =  DateTime.Now;
```

And in your UI cshtml file
retrieve that stored value from ViewBag like following

```
@{
    var CurrentDatetime = ViewBag.CurrentDatetime;
 }

<input type="date" name="end" value=@CurrentDatetime/>
```

**Note: If you not find this answer Helpful, i am requesting you to Provide some Detailed and precise Explanation regarding what you exactly looking for.**

Thanks.